# Custom Module Admin Grid View "Search by Keyword" Not Working

Tags: magento2, module

How to make my search bar work in my custom grid module? I have added the search field by inserting this code `<filterSearch name="fulltext"/>` inside my `<listingToolbar name="listing_top">` tag.

The search field have been displayed but it's not working, what should I do?

Answer (score 5):

Using the new declarative schema (2.3+):

1. on a *db_schema.xml* add:

```xml
<table name="something_grid">
    <index referenceId="SOME_INDENTIFIER" indexType="fulltext">
        <column name="custom_column_1"/>
        <column name="custom_column_2"/>
        <column name="custom_column_n"/>
    </index>
</table>
```

**Important:** if you are extending a preexisting grid with new columns, you will need to find it's `<module>_grid.xml` declaration and make sure to use the same `referenceId` for that table on your *db_schema.xml*

2. run a `bin/magento setup:upgrade`
3. have fun and buy me a coffee :D

Reference: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html#add-an-index

Answer (score 2):

`fulltext` search only work if you have add index in your database table.
to add Index in your table use below code.

```
$setup->getConnection()->addIndex(
    $setup->getTable('quote_id_mask'),
    $setup->getIdxName('quote_id_mask', ['masked_id']),
    ['masked_id']
);
```

[**Reference**](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/567)

Comment: Can you pls help me here? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/296226/77631

Answer (score 1):

**

A **full-text** search, also known as a **keyword** **search**, is a functionality that can produce more relevant results by scanning a considerable number of fields in the Magento 2 admin grid. Therefore, adding the full-text search in Magento 2 grid can help the admin search more efficiently and faster.

However, the Magento 2 **keyword** search functionality sometimes fails to work and might not provide **accurate** results. Thus, you can follow the below steps to fix the Magento 2 keyword search now working in the custom Module Admin Grid View,

To add the Full-text or Keyword search functionality in Magento 2 custom module admin grid view, you must **create** and **add** an **index** of the table.
You can do it by calling the **addIndex()** function in the below **file**.,

> \app\code\Vendor\Extension\Setup\InstallSchema.php

Below provided is the code to make an **index** of the table and add the **keyword search** functionality in Magento 2 Admin grid view:

```
$connection->addIndex(
                    'testtable', //table name'title',    // index name
                    [
                        'title'   // filed or column name 
                    ],           \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_FULLTEXT //type of index
                );
```

You must add the **table name** and **column names** in the above code to add the **keyword** search in Magento 2 admin grid view.

I hope the above solution helps you to resolve the **"Custom Module Admin Grid View "Search by Keyword" Not Working"** issue. However, if the issue persists, you can update it here.