# Magento 2 : Custom column filter with serialize data in UI grid

Tags: magento2, filter, ui-grid

I added product name column in my module ui grid. In my database, it's save product id.

I display successfully product name in column by product id. But, filter not working when I search by product name.

I just want to add custom field in collection when I do filter.

**Current grid collection array :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [rule_title] => {"1":"Rule 1","2":"Rule 1"}
            [status] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [rule_title] => {"1":"Rule 2","2":"Rule 2"}
            [status] => 1
        )
)
```

**Want array like this :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [rule_title] => {"1":"Rule 1","2":"Rule 1"}
            [status] => 1
            [rule_name] => Rule 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [rule_title] => {"1":"Rule 2","2":"Rule 2"}
            [status] => 1
            [rule_name] => Rule 2
        )
)
```

How to do that?

Comment: can you please add your code in question.

Comment: I tried to follow this code : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/226087/77631

Comment: But, where should I need to use _renderFiltersBefore() this function? I added in app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Page/Collection.php file.

Comment: yes, you can write in the model and if possible create a Separate Grid collection file and add filter there.

Comment: But, I don't know how to do that? can you please help me?

Comment: Check my updated question : I did that in app\code\Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Page\Grid\Collection.php

Comment: protected function _initSelect() {
 parent::_initSelect();
 echo "<pre/>";
 print_r($this->getData());
 exit;
}

Comment: `rule_title` is your db column and you want to extract Title from the JSON object and set it in `rule_name` right? If yes then why you don't create one column Rule_name in the table directly?

Comment: Nope. I can't because of requirement. Can you pls help based on this?

Comment: will try and let you know

Comment: Any update .......?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also face same issue and solved by this below code :

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Page/Grid/Collection.php

```
protected function _renderFiltersBefore() {
    $filters = $this->request->getParam('filters');
    if (isset($filters['your_field'])) {
        $match = sprintf('%%%s%%', substr($this->serializer->serialize(['your key' => $filters['your_field']]), 1, -1));
        $this->addFieldToFilter('your_field', ['like' => $match]);
    }
    parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
}
```

You need to inject this below class in your construct of **Collection.php** file

```
\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
\Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json $serializer
```

Your data is like :

```
{"1":"Rule 1","2":"Rule 1"}
```

Then, you can do like this

```
$match = sprintf('%%%s%%', substr($this->serializer->serialize(['1' => "Rule 1"]), 1, -1));
```

Hope, It will helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks.. !! It's working like charm.. !!