# Magento 2 - Fetch Customer Address Attribute

Tags: magento2, customer, magento-2.2.5, customer-address, customer-address-attribute

I need to fetch the value of customer address attribute just like we have product attribute

I am using `Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface` and created the instance from it

```
$addressRepository = $objectManager->create("Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface");
$address = $addressRepository->getById($customerId);
```

From `$address` instance, I am able to fetch the `default field or attribute` just like

```
$address->getFirstname();
```

The problem is, I am not able to fetch the newly created `customer address attribute`

For Example:
My newly created `customer address attribute` is `area` but I am not able to fetch it from `$address->getArea();`

Any help, experience and knowledge sharing would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have custom address attribute then you can get it's value by this:

```
echo $address->getCustomAttribute("area")->getValue();
```

This would treated as same way as customer custom attribute.

But the problem with above code is, if your attribute is dropdown, then it will return option id, not the text of option.

**Hope this will resolve your issue** :)

Comment: It looks great, let me check whether it is working or not

Comment: It worked like a charm :)

Comment: Good to hear that. +1 for answer acceptance :)

Comment: Do you know about this? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/296226/77631